# How to fetch a string from a line if the position of the string is not fixed | php

Tags: php

I want to fetch the value of `authMarket` and `authscheme` from the `Cookie`. However  its position is not fixed. See the below two examples.

```
Cookie: TANAUTH=9f8830f6378847f726e678beaa1deea3; MultisecureUserId=00198343; authMarket=be; website=YOUROFFICE; DST=R4; authscheme=SMS; 

Cookie: cuvid=cdf97045b3f041ba8de0358a7c432202; _ga=GA1.3.1409531768.1486113952; TANAUTH=cce09bb700c0c6c6c1d216ce616c23c3; MultisecureUserId=00198345; authMarket=be; website=YOUROFFICE; DST=R4; authscheme=SOFTTOKEN;
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: `$_COOKIE['authMarket']`..? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: How did you get these strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given a string

```
$string="Cookie: TANAUTH=9f8830f6378847f726e678beaa1deea3; MultisecureUserId=00198343; authMarket=be; website=YOUROFFICE; DST=R4; authscheme=SMS ";
```

you can use

```
$data=array_column( array_map(function($v) { return explode('=',trim($v));},explode(';',substr($string,strpos($string,':')+1))),1,0);


var_dump($data);
var_dump($data['TANAUTH'],$data['authMarket']);
```

ouput:

```
    array(6) {
      ["TANAUTH"]=>
      string(32) "9f8830f6378847f726e678beaa1deea3"
      ["MultisecureUserId"]=>
      string(8) "00198343"
      ["authMarket"]=>
      string(2) "be"
      ["website"]=>
      string(10) "YOUROFFICE"
      ["DST"]=>
      string(2) "R4"
      ["authscheme"]=>
      string(3) "SMS"

}

string(32) "9f8830f6378847f726e678beaa1deea3"
string(2) "be"
```

This works fine for your two examples.

However you must keep in mind that PHP has its native `$_SESSION` setting and fetching mechanisms.So you need to take a look  at this section of the manual and use the best method which fit the most your requirement.